# How should I respond to my parents saying bad things to me?

Tags: parents

My parents recently started cursing me about small things like not teaching my younger sister every day. They say things like you will be blind or nothing is going to go right for you. They started saying things which I haven't done. Please, can someone tell me what to do?

Comment: Have patience. Sit down & explain to your parents your situation and that you are trying your best. Your tone is important. Remember the story of Prophet Ibrahim (AS) who inspite of all that his father said to him, was most gracious to his father. Inshallah you will be rewarded for your Sabr. (If they beat you or something, try to speak your grandparents or close aunty to help you in this matter).

Comment: @Ahmed try to elaborate and post an answer!

Comment: Should you be teaching? Teaching is a specialised profession and they're better off getting a tutor; if its help with her homework that might be different...